# DateTime.Parse retornando hora errada

Tags: datetime, flutter

Olá, estou fazendo isso:

```
DateTime horaInicio = DateTime.parse(parsedJson['comeco']);
```

Valor do parsedJson:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver no parsedJson é `7:38:33` e é esse horário que eu queria, mas tenho como resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A função não está errada, o problema é que você não está levando em consideração o fuso horário (Time-zone).

Isso aqui é retornado em seu JSON:

> 2020-08-04T07:38:33-04:00

Está sendo convertido para:

> 2020-08-04 11:45:38.000Z

O horário "errado" é por causa do fuso horário "04:00".

> **Partes da data**
>
> **JSON:** 2020-08-04T07:38:33-04:00
>
> **Data:** 2020-08-04 (yyyy-MM-dd)
>
> **Hora:** 11:45:38.000 (hh:mm:ss:zzz)
>
> **Fuso:** 04:00

**Ajuste**

Você pode tentar utilizar o `toLocal()` no momentoda conversão

```
DateTime.parse(parsedJson['comeco']).toLocal()
```

Comment: Legal, eu entendi agora, mas como eu faço então pra ele pegar o fuso horário correto?

Comment: @JeffHenrique Tente fazer DateTime.parse(parsedJson['comeco']).toLocal()

Comment: Fuso horário justificaria a diferença nas horas, mas por que tem uma diferença nos minutos também?

Comment: @user140828 Existe todo um cálculo para ser gerado uma data e hora, daí tu tem que entrar nas classes para entender, essa diferença nos minutos/segundos se da por isso.

Comment: @Matheus, pode me dar uma referencia? Não acho que essa sua afirmação seja correta.

Comment: @user140828 O que falei realmente não faz sentido, mas nos meus testes aqui o minuto/segundo não foram alterados como citado na pergunta, apenas a hora sofreu alteração.